# How to read a file to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, file, nested

I want to create a list of lists from a file that contains the following data:

```
101 Rahul
102 Julie
103 Helena
104 Kally
```

**CODE**

```
lis = []

with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    for i in range(1,3,1):
        for data in f.read().split():
            lis.append(data)
print(lis)
```

**Output I Want**

```
[[101,Rahul] ,[102,Julie] ,[103,Helena] ,[104,Kally]]
```

**Output I m getting**

```
['101', 'Rahul', '102', 'Julie', '103', 'Helena', '104', 'Kally']
```

Comment: `lis = [data.split() for data in f]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
lis = []

with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    for i in range(1,3,1):
        for data in f.read().split():
            lis.append(data)
print(lis)
```

Note the two for loops, what you are doing is looping through each line, then through each item on that line.  You are then pushing each item individually into your list `lis`.
To get the output you want, you want to be pushing a list of the two items on each line into your list.
You are actually already generating this list of items with `f.read().split()`, so you just need to append this.
This leaves you with the following:

```
lis = []

with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    for i in range(1,3,1):
        #no second loop here
        data = f.read().split()
        lis.append(data)
print(lis)
```

This still doesn't give us the correct answer, the loop is the problem here, 
we can fix this by just reading each line ideomatically, without specifying any ranges:

```
lis = []

with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    for line in f:
        #no second loop here
        data = line.split()
        lis.append(data)
print(lis)
```

Comment: have you run your code, it doesn't work...it gives the wrong result

Comment: only your last example gives the expected output, your first and second example has an extra `:` after `line.split()`

Comment: yep, that was a typo. already removed.  - I was trying to approach it by fixing one item at a time, rather than presenting a complete solution with little explanation.

Comment: Thanks @baldrickk
Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could read line by line iterating on the handle or using `readlines()`, splitting each line, appending each result, etc... Fixing your code would require to remove the `range` loop which just reads the file 3 times (but only effectively reads once the first time), and append the splitted items of the lines, using a list comprehension to be more pythonic:

```
with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
     lis = [line.split() for line in f]
```

note that the cool thing about `line.split()` (without parameters) is that it gets rid of the line terminator(s) automatically.

but you can make it simpler: `csv` module does all the parsing for you:

```
import csv
with open("student_details.txt" , "r") as f:
   cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
   # iterate on rows and generate list of lists:
   result = list(cr)
```

Comment: I need to solve this problem without using any import.Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to do it by `list` comprehension as the following:

```
with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:
    lis = [line.split() for line in f]
```

or if you want to `loop` you can `loop` through the file without reading it:

```
with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    lis = []
    for line in f:
        lis.append(line.split())
```

Comment: okay but you don't need `line.rstrip()` in that particular case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If I don't `line.rstrip()` 2nd item will have `\n` at the end of it. Which will be add a new line when printing or so

Comment: nope, because `strip()` already does that for you (or your listcomp version is wrong BTW :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you are right :D then I was using it when I wasn't splitting, thanks for clearing that up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can split by lines:

```
lis = []

with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    for line in f:
       data = line.split()
       lis.append(data)
print(lis)
```

Result :

```
[['101', 'Rahul'], ['102', 'Julie'], ['103', 'Helena'], ['104', 'Kally']]
```

---

Or in a more compact way :

```
with open("student_details.txt" , "r+") as f:    
    lis = [line.split() for line in f]
print(lis)
```

Result :

```
[['101', 'Rahul'], ['102', 'Julie'], ['103', 'Helena'], ['104', 'Kally']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this alternative too. I'm using splitlines() method.

```
data = []
f = open('student_details.txt', 'r')
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    data.append([line])
print(data)
```